# Differences-in-difference Graph in R-Studio

Tags: r

I have a question for my project in R-Studio.

In my research I assume that the presence of peacekeepers can positively influence the political representation of women. In this regard, I have the independent variable "pko_dummy" (0 = no peacekeeping mission, 1 = peacekeeping mission) and the two dependent variables "parl_wom.per" and "exe_wom.per", which measure the percentage of women elected to parliament and ministerial cabinets respectively.
The dataset in question includes all African countries that experienced a war between 1990 and 2018. I would like to run a differences-in-difference model. The treatment group would be the war-torn countries with a PKO, the control group the war-torn countries without a PKO. The problem is that the year of intervention of peacekeeping missions is different from country to country, so I don't know how to create a graph in R-Studio to see if the parallel trend assumption can be fulfilled.

```
data <- structure(list(cown = c(432, 432, 432, 432, 432, 432, 432, 432, 
                                432, 432), 
                       year = c(1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 
                                                    1997, 1998, 1999), 
                       intensity_level = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
                                           0, 0), 
                       pa_dummy = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
                       pko_dummy = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
                       parl_wom.per = c(NA, NA, 0.023, 0.023, 0.023, 0.023, 
                                        0.023, 0.122449, 0.122449, 0.122449), 
                       exe_wom.per = c(0.0588235, 0.1052632, 0.0526316, 
                                       0.0952381, 0.1111111, 0.0555556, 
                                       0.125, 0.1176471, 0.2608696, 0.2727273), 
                       gender_mean = c(0, 0, 1.75, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
                       gender_art = c(0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
                       female_pko.per = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
                       lf_wom.per = c(0.60855, 0.60834, 0.6082, 0.60815, 
                                      0.6082, 0.60838, 0.60806, 0.60798, 
                                      0.60804, 0.60811), 
                       ss.per = c(0.0679799, 0.0723098, 0.0827134, 0.0837933, 
                                  0.0957365, 0.1073224, 0.1127522, 0.1228388, 
                                  0.1336761, 0.1510765), 
                       fdi.per = c(0.0021364, 0.0004424, -0.0077276, 0.001441, 
                                   0.0083661, 0.0411724, 0.009786, 0.0275705, 
                                   0.0032724, 0.0090061), 
                       ele.sy = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
                       polity = c(-7, NA, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5), 
                       mus.per = c(0.944, 0.944, 0.944, 0.944, 0.944, 
                                   0.944, 0.944, 0.944, 0.944, 0.944), 
                       cons_ref = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
                       jud_ind.per = c(0.4763113, 0.5237863, 0.5575284, 
                                       0.548066, 0.548066, 0.548066, 0.548066, 
                                       0.548066, 0.548066, 0.548066)), 
                  row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Welcome! Avoid using the image to show the data. Instead, add a reproducible sample of the data. Use dput(sample_data) to get the structure and add it here.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I tried to add the data sample but it is too big.

Comment: Is there any other chance to send you the data?

Comment: Try dput(head(sample_data, 10)

Comment: It should have worked now

Comment: Made the changes. This is how a reproducible sample should look like.

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you have any idea how I could carry out the differences-in-difference?

Comment: Will it work if we have a plot showing the average `parl_wom.per` of countries by year, so that  we could compare the average of countries with pko and without pko?